# slowly rotate an object towards another object

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, flash-cs4

I have an object that points in the direction of another object (i.e. it rotates to the direction that the second objects x and y coordinates are at) below is the code I use.

```
var distx = target.x - x;
var disty = target.y - y;

var angle:Number = Math.atan2(disty, distx);


var vx:Number = Math.cos(angle) * cspeed;
var vy:Number = Math.sin(angle) * cspeed;
rotation = angle * 180/Math.PI;

x += vx;
y += vy;
```

as you can see. Not only does it rotate towards the target object, but it also moves towards it too. When I play the movie, the object instantly points to the targeted object and moves towards it.

I would like for it to slowly turn towards the object instead of instantly turning towards it. anyone know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say try this function

```
function averageNums($a:Number, $b:Number, $f:Number=0.5):Number {
   var avg:Number = (Math.atan2( Math.sin($a)*($f) + Math.sin($b)*(1-$f) , Math.cos($a)*($f) + Math.cos($b)*(1-$f) ));
   return avg;
}
```

and
    rotation = averageNums(rotation/180*Math.PI,angle, 0.9)* 180/Math.PI;

the f number will let you have faster/slower rotation

there ARE issues with this way of doing it, like averaging 0 and 180

Comment: glad it works, just be aware of the issue pointed out, this would occur when the object is exactly 0 or 180 degrees off.
If you follow the trig there, what ends up happening is that the difference between the two y positions (that are exactly the same at that point) will be 0, and you can't devide by zero. So you might want to put an if statement to prevent the error event from happening

Answer (score 1):

What about using a Tween to do it?  You can use the built-in flash library [fl.transitions.Tween](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/transitions/Tween.html) or one of the many alternatives like [Tweener](http://code.google.com/p/tweener/) or [TweenLite](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenlite/).

For fl.transitions.Tween

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
var myTween:Tween = new Tween(this, "rotation", Regular.easeOut, this.rotation, angle * 180/Math.PI, 3, true);
```

Using Tweener:

```
import com.caurina.transitions.Tweener
Tweener.addTween(this, {rotation:angle * 180 / Math.PI, time:3, transition:"easeOutQuad"});
```

Using TweenLite:

```
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;
TweenLite.to(this, 3, {rotation:angle * 180 / Math.PI, ease:Quad.easeOut});
```

Comment: Not too farmiluar with the significance of programmatic tweening.

Answer (score 1):

hey i know this post is a bit old but i'v been looking for a solution myself for this and finally found a way to solve this problem! yey me :D

this loop will make myAngle turn towards the mouse

```
        //loop
    function loop(e:Event) {
        var targetAngle:Number=Math.atan2(myStage.mouseY-y,myStage.mouseX-x);

        if(Math.abs(myAngle-targetAngle)>Math.PI){
            if(targetAngle>0){
                targetAngle-=Math.PI*2;
            }else{
                targetAngle+=Math.PI*2;
            }
        }

        if(myAngle>Math.PI){
            myAngle -=Math.PI*2;
        }

        if(myAngle<-Math.PI){
            myAngle +=Math.PI*2;
        }

        //this is to check if the angle is wide enough, otherwise myAngle will jiggle back and forth
        if (Math.abs(myAngle-targetAngle)>0.1) {
            if (myAngle-targetAngle<0) {
                myAngle+=0.1;
            } else {
                myAngle-=0.1;
            }
        }
```